# Is there any way to migrate manual version control to git?

Tags: git, version-control

Using git, but I have some v1, v2, v3, etc version control in separately named folders. Is there any way to combine these into git's version control?

To elaborate, the subfolder hierarchy is

```
DVT-SW(master)
|
 \
  *bunch of other folders*
|
 \
  ProjectName_Project
  |
   \
    v1
    |
     \ProjectName
  |
   \
    v2
    |
     \ProjectName
  |
   \
    v3
    |
     \ProjectName
```

where the SignalGeneration folder in each version folder has an incrementally designed version of the project. Is there any way to add v2/v3/v4's SignalGeneration project to v1's SignalGeneration project as incremental commits?

Comment: Of course there is—there are many ways; the question is, what sort of *result* do you want? If you want `v1` to come first, then `v2`, then `v3`, then whatever you have now, *that* requires "rewriting history". If you're OK with just recording v1-through-v3 as "ancient history we like to forget about", that's a lot easier.

Comment: Do V1, V2 and V3 folders have alread managed in three separate git repos or do they just normal folders?

Comment: @torek I updated the question hopefully that explains it?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT they all exist in the same repo but updated manually and stored in separate folders as separate projects (I didn't know git retained previous versions I was basically using it as Google Drive haha)